# If $H \leq G$ has index 3, $N_G(H) \in \{H,G \}$.

Tags: group-theory

In Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra text, page 91, example (1) they write:

> Let $H=\langle (1 \;2) \rangle \leq S_3$. Since $H$ is of prime index 3 in $S_3$, by Lagrange's Theorem the only possibilities for $N_{S_3}(H)$ are $H$ or $S_3$.

I don't understand what $H$ being of prime index 3 has to do with this. I can easily arrive at the result be observing that $$H \leq N_{S_3}(H) \leq S_3 $$
and applying Lagrange's theorem to get $2 \big||N_{S_3}(H)|$ and $|N_{S_3}(H)| \big|6$. However, how can I use the fact that there is a prime number (3) of left cosets of $H$ in $S_3$ to arrive at the same result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are a prime number of left cosets of a subgroup $H$ then that subgroup is maximal in the sense you describe - if $H \leq M \leq G$ then $M = H$ or $M = G$. This is because $[G : M][M : H] = [G : H]$, so if $[G : H]$ is prime, then either $[G:M]$ or $[M:H]$ must be 1.